# Get the number of days remaining until date in string

Tags: php, date

I have a string `$newAfter` that outputs like `Wednesday 9th of March 2016 11:59:59 PM`.

I use this code to calculate the days left:

```
$daysleft = floor(($newAfter - time()) / 86400);
```

this is the result I get:

```
-16559
```

I want the days remaining up leading up to the date in string.

Comment: `$newAfter` has invalid datetime format, `strtotime($newAfter)` returns 1.1.1970. Use correct datetime format, eg. `2016-03-09 11:59:59`

Comment: this is what I have for $newAfter `$newAfter = gmdate("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A", strtotime($notAfter));`

Comment: i want to be able to show the full date as sown above and the days remaining.. not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can't subtract days from that format string, you'll need to subtract them as integers of use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects:

```
$notAfter = 'Thu, 28 Apr 2016 03:22:56 +0200';
$today = new DateTime;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $notAfter);
$diff = $date->diff($today);
echo "{$diff->days} days left.";
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/olHXV3)

Comment: Hi @Ghost - $notAfter is a reference from an array, its original value looks like this `Thu, 28 Apr 2016 03:22:56 +0200` I then converted it to gmdate `newAfter` is that format okay to use directly in your code?

Comment: @user3436467 oh okay, you can check out the revision i made, so thats the raw input format

Comment: ok cool, i tried that as the raw input and it works correctly with your code. Thanks always Ghost

Comment: @Rizier123 wow what is that? never used that one before,  found new styling =) thanks Rizier